# div content not loading after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a landing page, where I'm loading content from `fetch_pages.php` using Ajax pagination, in `fetch_pages.php`, I'm calling Ajax when a user click a button and reloading a `div` calling `connect()` function, here when that `div` reloads, it becomes empty, not getting the exact solution. Kindly help.

Partial code of `fetch_pages.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php'; //include config file

    $UserID=$_SESSION['uid'];
    $UserType=$_SESSION['utype'];

    $GLOBALS['lks']=0;
    $GLOBALS['cmnts']=0;
    $GLOBALS['disabled']="";

//sanitize post value
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

//throw HTTP error if page number is not valid
if(!is_numeric($page_number)){
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid page number!');
    exit();
}

//get current starting point of records
$position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);
?>
    <!---post start -->
    <div id="mainsectionID">
<?php
//fetch records using page position and item per page. 
$results = $linkID1->query("select slno,posts,img_link,video_link,likes,comments,shares,post_date,post_time,UserID from user_posts where UserID='$UserID' or UserID in(select MyFriendsUserID from user_connections where MyUserID='$UserID') or UserID in(select MyUserID from user_connections where MyFriendsUserID='$UserID') order by slno desc LIMIT $position, $item_per_page")
or
die(mysqli_error());

//output results from database
?>

<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
{ //fetch values
                    $CUID=$row['UserID'];

                    $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select Name,Company,Designation,UserType from user_details where UserID=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $CUID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($Name2,$Company2,$Designation2,$UType);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $stmt->close();

                    $UT2='';
                    if($UType=='A')
                    {
                        $UT2='Advertiser';
                    }
                    else if($UType=='P')
                    {
                        $UT2='Publisher';
                    }

                    $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select ProfilePic from user_picture where UserID=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $CUID);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->bind_result($PPic);
                    $stmt->fetch();
                    $stmt->close();
        ?>
            <div class="mainsection" id="mainsection<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>">
          <div>
            <div class="pull-left postimage"><?php echo "<img src=profile_pic/".$PPic ." />"; ?></div>
            <div class="pull-left posttext">
                <div class="postname"><?php echo $Name2; ?></div>
                <p><?php echo $UT2." - ".$Designation2." - ".$Company2; ?></p></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="postdowntxt"><p><?php echo $row['posts']; ?></p></div>
            <hr>
          </div>

          <div class="btnclasess" id="likescommentID<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>">
              <div class="likescomment"><?php dataLC($linkID1, $row['slno'],$CUID); ?><a style="padding-right: 7px" href="#"><?php if($GLOBALS['lks']==0){echo '';}else{ echo $GLOBALS['lks']." Likes"; } ?></a><a href="#"><?php if($GLOBALS['cmnts']==0){echo '';}else{ echo $GLOBALS['cmnts']." Comments"; } ?></a></div>
             <div class="pull-left likebtn"><button <?php echo $GLOBALS['disabled']; ?> class="btn" id="likeButton<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>" onClick="connect(<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="margin-right: 6px;"></i>Like</button></div>
             <button class="pull-left btnhideshow show_hide" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>"><li class="fa fa-comments show_hide" style="margin-right: 6px;"></li>Comment</button>
             <button class="pull-left btnhideshow show_hide"><li class="fa fa-share-alt show_hide" style="margin-right: 6px;"></li>Share</button>
             <div class="clear"></div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
......rest codes goes here.......

<?php 
    function dataLC($linkID1, $val, $CUID)
    {
        $UserID=$CUID;
        $LgUserID=$_SESSION['uid'];

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select likes,comments from user_posts where slno=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($lksD,$cmntsD);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $GLOBALS['lks']=$lksD;
        $GLOBALS['cmnts']=$cmntsD;

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select count(slno) from user_posts_likes where MyUserID=? and FrUserID=? and PostID=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $UserID,$UserID,$val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($cnt);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if($cnt>=1)
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="enabled";
        }

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select count(slno) from user_posts_likes where MyUserID=? and FrUserID=? and PostID=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $UserID,$LgUserID,$val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($cnt2);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if($cnt2>=1)
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="enabled";
        }

        $stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select count(slno) from user_posts_likes where MyUserID=? and FrUserID=? and PostID=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $LgUserID,$UserID,$val);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($cnt3);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        if($cnt3>=1)
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="disabled";
        }
        else
        {
            $GLOBALS['disabled']="enabled";
        }
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function connect(num) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "user-likes.php?id="+num,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data=='1')
            {  
                $("#likescommentID"+num).load(" #likescommentID"+num);
            }
        }
        });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: you have ajax type POST, and yet you send id param via url (get) `?id="+num`

Comment: url: "user-likes.php?id="+num why are you passing your values throug get when the type is post

Comment: @Cashbee it's still possible to read querystring values when receiving a POST request.

Comment: @rupesh same as I wrote to cashbee, this needn't be a problem necessarily

Comment: Jahangir, where is the code of user-likes.php? Do we know if it definitely receives the request, processes it correctly and returns the content in the response? Does `data` in your "success" function actually contain anything?

Comment: @Cashbee...........thats not the problem because the file "user-likes.php" is doing the required things. The only problem is getting when calling "$("#likescommentID"+num).load(" #likescommentID"+num);"

Comment: use var_dump() for PHP and alert() or console.log() for javascript to debug your code and find out where your problem lies. **Edit:** for example write `console.log(data);`  as your first line in success function of ajax

Comment: And `$("#likescommentID"+num).load(" #likescommentID"+num);` doesn't make much sense - it seems to try and load itself?? What purpose would that have? Also there's an error - the selector shouldn't have a space at the start. .load() is for fetching remote content from a server - it's supposed to make another ajax request. But you already made an ajax request to user-likes.php - doesn't that return your content?

Comment: @ADyson.............The page user_likes.php does not return anything, it just doing an insert function to db. Which is working perfectly. Just the content of the div is not reloading.

Comment: Where are you trying to reload the div from exactly? Your code is just trying to refresh the div with its own existing contents (and doing it wrong, because of the bad selector) which seems pretty pointless, if it would even work at all.

Comment: What do you mean by 'reloading'? Calling `load()` with the current element id as the argument won't actually do anything at all

Comment: The same process is working perfectly before applying the pagination part, after implementing pagination, the div becomes empty while calling the load() function

Comment: @JahangirAlam Well, we don't know what you changed in order to add, so it's hard to comment. You can see what you modified, so that's the place to start looking. My mine and Rory's comments still stand, it's clear that your .load() command makes no sense. If you explain where you actually want to get new data from for your div, then maybe we can help you.

Comment: When i am calling "$("#likescommentID"+num).load(" #likescommentID"+num);", then my div "<div class="btnclasess" id="likescommentID<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>">" is calling a function "dataLC($linkID1, $row['slno'],$CUID);", which will update the div with required data

Comment: That won't happen because you haven't made a call to the server as far as I can see. You've tried to load the same selector directly from the page which makes no sense. The .load() function needs to accept a URL not a CSS selector.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem resolved, called the pagination part again. Thnx